# Database connections/queries as tied to unity gameobjects

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an application in Unity that needs to access a database to provide information about a set number of GameObjects.

Currently, I've attached a script to each GameObject that establishes a connection, queries the database, and fills some public variables, something like this:

```
public class Fill : MonoBehaviour {
    static string connectString = 
    "Server=blah;" +
        "Database=blah.org,3500;" +
        "User ID=blahman;" +
        "Password=blah42;";

    static SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectString);
    public string PublicVar;
    void Start () {
        string sCommand = string.Concat("SELECT blah from blah.table where row =", transform.GameObject.name);

        //FILL PUBLIC VARIABLE FOR _______
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sCommand, cn);
        cn.Open ();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        int rec = da.Fill (dataTable);
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) {
            //Debug.Log ("--- Row --- ");
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray){
                //Debug.Log ("Item ");
                //Debug.Log (item);
               PublicVar = item.ToString();
            }
        }
        cn.Close();

    } 


    }
```

I'm currently experiencing some considerable time overhead when beginning to run the scene, obviously because the database is being connected and queried to in the 'Start' method for many different gameobjects (>20).

My question is this: where does this overhead come from? Is it in the queries themselves, the connection, the data adapter? Would it be better design to establish one global connection or a Singleton and have all the scripts access that? My current model seemed the most intuitive, but I need better performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remote database adds latency. Say 100 ms per request.

Select of individual objects is inefficient, get a list of all objects, join tables if necessary, to read the data only once and thus reduce the latency to a single request of 100 ms (plus data transfer) rather than 20 times 100 ms.